# Prove that an integer monic polynomial with nonzero constant term and exactly one root outside the open unit disk is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

$\textbf{Problem:}$ Let $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a nonconstant monic polynomial, and let $\mathbb{D} = \{z ∈ C : |z| < 1\}$ be the open unit disk in the complex plane. Suppose that $f$ has exactly one root not in $\mathbb{D}$, and that its constant term $a_0$ is nonzero. Show that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

$\textbf{Might be helpful:}$ Since only one root - let's call that root $\alpha_1$ - is not in $\mathbb{D}$, then $a_0<|\alpha_1|$. (the constant term of any polynomial is equal to the product of its roots over $\mathbb{C}$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f=gh$ is a proper factorisation, one of its factors, $g$ say, has all zeroes in the unit disc. What could its constant term be?

Comment: If $f=gh$ is a proper factorisation over $\mathbb{Q}$ with g having all zeroes in the unit disc, then the constant term in $g$ must be a rational number between -1 and 1. I still don't get it, what's the next step?

Comment: Ah, but your polynomial is over $\Bbb Z$, not just over $\Bbb Q$!

Comment: I see what you're hinting at - that $a_0=0$ since it must be an integer, but I don't see why you would be saying that - $g$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, not over $\mathbb{Z}$!
Therefore we don't have that restriction for the constant term in $g$.

Comment: Never mind, just remembered about Gauss's lemma.. thanks!

(Gauss's lemma: if a non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients is irreducible over the integers, then it is also irreducible if it is considered as a polynomial over the rationals.)